# how can I set Alias Redirection in AWS S3 website CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a main website at apex domain (xxx.com) working, now have a short term project which is a landing page only, use Gatsby4(React) deployed as all static files at a S3 bucket, and setup proper Cloudfront distribution for https working

now have https://landingpage.xxx.com which is working, but it's long and hard to remember, want to also set a short alias,

when user enter `lp.xxx.com` in address bar, it should do HTTP 301 Redirect to destination https://landingpage.xxx.com; I have setup this `lp.xxx.com` in Route53 as CNAME `landingpage.xxx.com` and add `lp.xxx.com` to Cloudfront Altname,

So now https://lp.xxx.com is working (as well as https://landingpage.xxx.com) but it works like 2 different entrances, with no redirection,

wonder is there an easy redirection rule setup I missed somewhere? avoid changing the Gatsby4(React) code; does this require some Lambda@Edge function to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a CloudFront function redirect resolved it:

modified from this sample code https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html

```js
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var headers = request.headers;
    var host = request.headers.host.value;

    if (host !== 'landingpage.xxx.com') {
        var response = {
            statusCode: 302,
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers:
                { "location": { "value": 'https://landingpage.xxx.com' } }
            }
        return response;
    }
    return request;
}
```